# html button that change images located in the same position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using HTML5 with Sublime and I want to create a button that makes visible or hidden two images alternatively located in the same place. So if I click the button should appear the first image and if I click the button another time the first image should disappear and should appear the second one and so on.
However I don't know how to locate the images in the same place.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Prova Preparazione</title>
    <script src="jsTs.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssTs.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h3>Cos’è Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
        Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa. Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.
    <br>
    <h3>Perchè lo utilizziamo?</h3>
        È universalmente riconosciuto che un lettore che osserva il layout di una pagina viene distratto dal contenuto testuale se questo è leggibile. Lo scopo dell’utilizzo del Lorem Ipsum è che offre una normale distribuzione delle lettere (al contrario di quanto avviene se si utilizzano brevi frasi ripetute, ad esempio “testo qui”), apparendo come un normale blocco di testo leggibile. Molti software di impaginazione e di web design utilizzano Lorem Ipsum come testo modello. Molte versioni del testo sono state prodotte negli anni, a volte casualmente, a volte di proposito (ad esempio inserendo passaggi ironici).
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="myDiv" >
        <button type="button" onclick="showImage()">Change image!</button> 
        <img src="http://random-ize.com/lorem-ipsum-generators/lorem-ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg" alt="Lorem" id="myImageId">
        <img src="http://www.metal-archives.com/images/1/5/5/0/15500_logo.jpg" alt="Lorem2" id="myImageId2">
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css code:

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 510px;
}

div {
    column-count: 2;
    padding-left: 50px
    padding-right: 50px;

}

button {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;

}
/*
div img {
    margin-left: 735px;
    width:304px;
    height:228px;
    visibility:hidden;
} */

#myImageId {
    margin-left: 55px;
    width:304px;
    height:228px;
    visibility:visible;

}

#myImageId2 {
    margin-left: 55px;
    width:304px;
    height:228px;
    visibility:visible;

}

#myDiv {
    display: flex;
}

#myCanvas {
    margin-left: 55px;
    width:304px;
    height:228px;
    visibility:visible;
    border:1px solid black;

}
```

And finally the js code:

```
function showImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById('myImageId');
    var img2 = document.getElementById('myImageId2');
    if( img.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        img2.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Instead of visibility :hidden/visible use display:block/none

Answer (score 0):

You also have to use `display` to show the images in the same position:

```
if( img.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        img.style.display = 'none';
        img2.style.visibility = 'visible';
        img2.style.display  = 'block';
    } else {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        img.style.display = 'block';
        img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        img2.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

`visibility="hidden"` will make the image invisible but it will retain it's display space.

Comment: @MicheledellaMea - glad I helped. please vote-up and mark as answer by clicking the check sign! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Put the two images in a container, lets say image-container

```
<div class='image-container'>
<div id="myDiv" >
<button type="button" onclick="showImage()">Change image!</button> 
        <img src="http://random-ize.com/lorem-ipsum-generators/lorem-ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg" alt="Lorem" id="myImageId">
        <img src="http://www.metal-archives.com/images/1/5/5/0/15500_logo.jpg" alt="Lorem2" id="myImageId2">
</div>
</div>
```

Give image-container a certain height and position relative, and give the two images position absolute.

```
.image-contaner{
position: relative;
height: 228px;
width: 304px;
}
#myImageId {
    margin-left: 55px;
    width:304px;
    height:228px;
    visibility:visible;
position: absolute;
}

#myImageId2 {
    margin-left: 55px;
    width:304px;
    height:228px;
    visibility:visible;
position: absolute;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `visibility`, you could use the property `display` like so:

css:

```
#myImageId {
    margin-left: 55px;
    width: 304px;
    height: 228px;
    display: block;
}
#myImageId2 {
    margin-left: 55px;
    width: 304px;
    height: 228px;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function showImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById('myImageId');
    var img2 = document.getElementById('myImageId2');
    if( img.style.display == 'block') {
        img.style.display = 'none';
        img2.style.display = 'block';
    } 
    else {
        img.style.display = 'block';
        img2.style.display= 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS position. Just set the two images' position to absolute. Remember to set the outer div position to relative.

Here is a simple CSS snippet

```
#myDiv {
  position: relative;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

the two images will be in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CSS `display` property instead of `visibility`.

The reason for this is that if you make an element invisible using `visibility`, the browser considers that it still takes up space on the page, it's just not visible. Whereas using the `display` property it will remove the element from its space calculations, meaning in your case that the second image will shuffle up into the space previously occupied by the first one.
CSS:

```
#myImageId {
  margin-left: 55px;
  width:304px;
  height:228px;
  display:block;
}

#myImageId2
{
  display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
if( img.style.display == 'none') {
    img.style.display = 'none';
    img2.style.display  = 'block';
} else {
    img.style.display = 'block';
    img2.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short but simple

```
#myDiv img{
   position: absolute;
   padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `.hide {display: none;}` in CSS you can also use this for more elements.

```
var hide = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
var j = 1;

function hideimg() {
  for (var i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {
    hide[i].style = "display:none;";
  }
  if (j < hide.length) {
    hide[j].style = "display:block;";
    j++;
  } else {
    j = 0;
    hide[j].style = "display:block;";
    j = 1;
 }
}
```